# Not Getting Search value in Sencha Touch using searchfield

Tags: search, sencha-touch-2, predicate

I want to display predictive text in search field, value for predictive text which comes from server. Here is my code so far:

**View:**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AutoSearch', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    alias : 'widget.mainPanel',

    config: {
     store : 'AutoSearchStore',



     itemTpl:  '<div class="myWord">'+
         '<div>Word is --<b>{name}</b>--- after search!!!</div>' +
         '</div>',

     emptyText: '<div class="myWord">No Matching Words</div>',

  items: [
                 {
                     xtype: 'toolbar',
                     docked: 'top',

                     items: [
                         {
                             xtype: 'searchfield',
                             placeHolder: 'Search...',
                             itemId: 'searchBox'
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             ]  

    }
});
```

**Store:**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.store.AutoSearchStore',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 

config:
{
    model: 'MyApp.model.AutoSearchModel',
    autoLoad:true,
    id:'Contacts',
    proxy:
    {
        type: 'ajax',
      url: 'http://alucio.com.np/trunk/dev/sillydic/admin/api/word/categories/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363', 

        reader:
        {
                rootProperty:''
        }
    }
}
});
```

**Model:**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.AutoSearchModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['MyApp.model.AutoSearchModelMenu'],
    config: {
        fields: [
        {name:'data', mapping: 'data'},
        {name: 'name'},
        ],       
    },
});
```

and

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.AutoSearchModelMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'name',
        ],
       belongsTo: "MyApp.model.AutoSearchModel"
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SearchAutoComplete', {
 extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

 config: {
  profile: Ext.os.deviceType.toLowerCase(),
  stores : ['MyApp.store.AutoSearchStore'],
  models : ['MyApp.model.AutoSearchModel'],
  refs: {
   myContainer: 'mainPanel'
  },
  control: {
   'mainPanel': {
    activate: 'onActivate'
   },
   'mainPanel searchfield[itemId=searchBox]' : {
    clearicontap : 'onClearSearch',
    keyup: 'onSearchKeyUp'
   }
  } 

 },

 onActivate: function() {
  console.log('Main container is active--Search');
 },

 onSearchKeyUp: function(searchField) {
  queryString = searchField.getValue();
  console.log(this,'Please search by: ' + queryString);

  var store = Ext.getStore('AutoSearchStore');
  store.clearFilter();

  if(queryString){
   var thisRegEx = new RegExp(queryString, "i");
   store.filterBy(function(record) {
    if (thisRegEx.test(record.get('name'))) {
     return true;
    };
    return false;
   });
  }

 },

 onClearSearch: function() {
  console.log('Clear icon is tapped');
  var store = Ext.getStore('AutoSearchStore');
  store.clearFilter();
 },

 init: function() {
  console.log('Controller initialized for SearchAutoComplete');
 }

});
```

Json Data Looks Like:

```js
"data":[
{
    "name":"paint",
    "author":"admin",
    "word_id":"1",
    "category":"Business",
    "is_favourite":"yesStar"
},
{
    "name":"abacus",
    "author":"admin",
    "word_id":"2",
    "category":"Education",
    "is_favourite":"yesStar"
},
{
    "name":"abate",
    "author":"admin",
    "word_id":"3",
    "category":"Education",
    "is_favourite":"noStar"
},
{
    "name":"testing adsf",
    "author":"admin",
    "word_id":"7",
    "category":"Education",
    "is_favourite":"noStar"
},
{
    "name":"sprite",
    "author":"admin",
    "word_id":"6",
    "category":"Business",
    "is_favourite":"noStar"
},
{
    "name":"newword",
    "author":"admin",
    "word_id":"8",
    "category":"Architecture",
    "is_favourite":"noStar"
}
]
})
```

If I type "A", then it displays `No Matching Words`, but I have words from "A" on json coming from server. How to solve this problem?

Any idea!

Code Sources [Link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/sencha-touch-search-field-example.html)

Comment: Your code is not in the best shape: Store reader is not set (JSON, root:'data'). Model maps data to data, though there is no data, but instead it should have "name", "author", "word_id", ... Why two models?  In the controller you are setting global vars - don't. Can you tell us, where you are stuck? Is the store loaded at all? Does the list display anything?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using two models but just one thing you need to specify in AutoSearchStore :

```
reader:
        {
                rootProperty:'data'
        }
```

instead of

```
reader:
        {
                rootProperty:''
        }
```

to get the expected results in the list.

Hope this will be helpful :)